# Change inputs of the same class based on content of a column

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following code, which if any input of a class is changed all of the same class will change:

```js
$('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1s', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(".c1s").prop("checked", true);
    $(".c1n").prop("checked", false);
  }
});

$('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1n', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(".c1n").prop("checked", true);
    $(".c1s").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TableTest" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>Name</tr>
    <tr>Has a car?</tr>
    <tr>Has a dog?</tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="column1" class="c1s" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="column1" class="c1n" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="column2" class="c1s" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="column2" class="c1n" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="column3" class="c1s" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="column3" class="c1n" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1c177pp7/

My new challange is the following, based on the very same example, now it would only have to set the same inputs (Yes/No) where the column Name is the same. If I click on 'Yes' input radio, only those 'Yes' where the name is Peter should change, ignoring mark.

I am thinking of two approches here:

1. Check directly the content of the , I will have to think how to get the value of the row clicked then iterate through all the table and apply the change where those are the same.
2. I can set the class for the column Name to the same value based on the name(when the table is created automatically), this would make change the current code not  only check the class of the input (c1s/c1n) but also the class of that  of the row that has been clicked.

What do you recommend me? Can you guide me a little? I hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
            $('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1s', function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                   var name= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:first-child:contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1s").prop("checked", true);
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:first-child:contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1n").prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
            $('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1n', function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                   var name= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:first-child:contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1s").prop("checked", false);
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:first-child:contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1n").prop("checked", true);
                }
            });
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1c177pp7/2/)

**EDIT**

For second `td` this will work

```
            $('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1s', function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                   var name= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:nth-child(2):contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1s").prop("checked", true);
                    $('#TableTest').find('td:nth-child(2):contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1n").prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
            $('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1n', function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                   var name= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:nth-child(2):contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1s").prop("checked", false);
                   $('#TableTest').find('td:nth-child(2):contains("'+name+'")').closest('tr').find(".c1n").prop("checked", true);
                }
            });
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1c177pp7/3/)

Comment: Very interesting and works like a charm... But for my example the <td> to look for the name is the second one, so I used the sam code but instead of 'td:first-child I'm using td:eq(1), which returns the correct value but doesn't work

Comment: @AlejandroA You can use `td:nth-child(2):contains("'+name+'")` for second child

Comment: Sorry I couldn't access the site during the weekend! It worked like a charm dude! Really thankfull :D!!!!

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: @AlejandroA see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I tested out what you said and ended up doing this.
This works while the  first td has the name.

Try this please

```
                $('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1s', function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    $(".c1s").prop("checked", false);
                    $(".c1n").prop("checked", false);
                    var tdParent = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text();
                    $(".c1s").each(function(index,el){
                            var getMyParent = $(el).parent().siblings(":first");
                        if($(getMyParent).text() == tdParent){
                           $(el).prop("checked", true);
                        }
                    });

                }

            });


            $('#TableTest').on('click', '.c1n', function () {

                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    $(".c1n").prop("checked", false);
                    $(".c1s").prop("checked", false);

                    var tdParent = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text();
                    $(".c1n").each(function(index,el){
                            var getMyParent = $(el).parent().siblings(":first");
                        if($(getMyParent).text() == tdParent){
                           $(el).prop("checked", true);
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```